# Run Internet Explorer as a different user

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, impersonation, runas

I'm trying to launch Internet Explorer with a different user to access a website that requires single sign on.

Below is the code that I'm using. It doesn't produce any errors but IE doesn't launch at all, not even the process.

```
Try

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(IExplorerPath, Username, ConvertToSecureString(Password), Domain)

    Success = True

Catch ex As Exception

    Success = False
    Error_Message = ex.Message

End Try
```

I also tried the following variation with the same result (nothing):

```
Try

    Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo()

    psi.Filename = IExplorerPath
    psi.UserName = Username
    psi.Domain = Domain
    psi.Password = ConvertToSecureString(Password)
    psi.UseShellExecute = False
    Process.Start(psi)

    Success = True

Catch ex As Exception

    Success = False
    Error_Message = ex.Message

End Try
```

This is the ConvertToSecureString function:

```
Function ConvertToSecureString(ByVal str As String)
    Dim password As New SecureString
    For Each c As Char In str.ToCharArray
        password.AppendChar(c)
    Next
    Return password
End Function
```

Comment: Surely it must throw some kind of error... Why not comment out the `Try/Catch` statement and let your debugger handle the crash instead so you can inspect it properly? -- Also, have you actually checked the Task Manager and seen that no IE process is started? I've never launched a process as a different user from code before, but what if it starts in their session and not the current one? Then you wouldn't be able to see the window. Try entering your own credentials and see what happens.

Comment: Test results: 1) Commenting out the Try/Catch generates an error saying that the username/password are incorrect/unknown, which it's odd because I tried doing it manually (shift + right click the IE executable) and it does work. 2) Yes, I checked the task manager an nothing there. 3) I used my credentials and it does work.

Comment: If that's the case (that it's being launched in their session) what should I change in my code to make it show in the current one?

Comment: There could be an error in `ConvertToSecureString`.

Comment: If that's the case, it should have thrown an error with my credentials. I also use that function for other scripts

Comment: _"Commenting out the Try/Catch generates an error saying that the username/password are incorrect/unknown"_ to me sounds like an error related to credentials. Even if that function works for other stuff, how can you be sure that it fits the `Process` class's needs? Also, to this point we don't know if it's launched in that users session or not as it never gets to that point (since the process fails to start at all).

Comment: I don't have the time to inspect it now, but please update your question with the code for the `ConvertToSecureString()` function so that we can verify if it's correct or not (even more important giving us a better chance of reproducing the problem). By the way, have you verified that the domain you specify is correct?

Comment: I added the code for the ConvertToSecureString function. Yes, when I run it with cmd it works

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've been searching a lot a solution for this and if you have it you deserve a Nobel price. In the mean time, if it helps anyone this is the workaround that I had to use:

Use Process.Start to run a .bat file that contains the following code:

```
runas /user:User@Domain.com "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

Then, when the command prompt appears I use the Send Keys to type in the password and press Enter.

This launches IE with different credentials. But again, there should be a better way.

Comment: FWIW an improvement would be to [**redirect the process's standard input**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18577/How-to-redirect-Standard-Input-Output-of-an-applic) and write the password to that. Inputting it using `SendKeys` is not very safe (my solution isn't that safe either, but it's _safer_).

Comment: Also you don't have to create a batch file. You can open a CMD instance directly by creating an instance of the [**`ProcessStartInfo` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) with the process name and arguments, like so: `Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C runas /user:User@Domain ""C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe""")`.

Comment: (Sorry for the spam) Or even better the non-hardcoded version: `Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C runas /user:User@Domain """ & Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), "Internet Explorer", "iexplore.exe") & """")`

Comment: I like your approach, it's better than having a batch file hanging out there. Thanks @VisualVincent

Comment: Glad I could help, even though we didn't manage to solve your original problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may / may not work. Try to launch your website that requires single sign on in "CHROME", hit F-12, go to Application Tab -> Cookies -> Click on your site link. on left hand side look for something that represent your session id, may be JSESSIONID or similar, copy that. Now open your Internet Explorer, hit F-12 and manually create that JSESSIONID by running this command in console window

```
document.cookie = "JSESSIONID=<your-session-id-from-chrome"
```

hit play button to execute script
Refresh your browser